# PowerVault MD3000 Password Reset Console Password

Tags: storage, password, dell, reset, dell-powervault

I need to reset the password on a Dell PowerVault MD3000. I have the necessary password reset cable and am able to get to the point where I am prompted for the "password from Dell Technical Support" (see ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_powervault/powervault-md3000_User%27s%20Guide_en-us.pdf). Unfortunately, since I got the device from ebay, Dell Technical Support wants proof of transfer of ownership before they'll provide any support. I can't provide such, as I don't know the original owner's contact details.

Does anyone know if this password is specific to the unit, or if it is a generic password, and if so, how I can obtain it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I didn't work with this array model but I worked a lot with Sun STK2500 or IBM DC 3400 model lines and they are all just re-branded LSI Engenio arrays (1532/1932). In case of Sun and IBM, it was a generic password and IMO it is the same for Dell.

I guess you know how to establish a serial connection to that gear. You need serial cable with PS2/Mini-DIN connector but I guess you got it with the array.

The procedure how to get to the array service interface is described in that aforementioned Dell document so I assume that you are able to get to password prompt.

[image]

The default password should be supportDell

[image]